# How to use secrets created via Hashicorp VAULT on Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am preparing an application to production. Topic I want help with is using the secret values I created on vault. I inject my secrets on a pod but I don't know how to reach them. I am using helm charts for my entire application and have 8 microservices.

Here I can read my injected secrets for TESTING on my vault pod which is deployed as an helm chart;

Key                 Value

---

refresh_interval    768h
password            sUp3rS3cUr3P@ssw0rd
username            dbuser

I wonder how to use my "password" on one of my microservice yaml for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are injecting your secrets to the pod, you should be able to know what is the path in which the secrets are located in, and what are the secret's files names.

If that is the case, you can expose an ENV variable `SECRETS_DIR_PATH` via `ConfigMap` which will contain the path to your secrets directory in your pod, e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
..
data:
  SECRETS_DIR_PATH: "/mnt/store/<appName>/secrets"
```

Once you have exposed this ENV variable, you could use it in your application and read the secret file. Example (using java `Dotnev`)

```java
var secretsDirPath = dotenv.get(SECRETS_DIR_PATH);
var secrets = Secrets.create(secretsDirPath);
var mySecret = secrets.getSecret("mySecret")
```

This example assumes you have a `Secrets` package that manages the reading and fetching of your secrets. Of course you can simply read them as a file. An advantage to having a package manage the secrets is you can perform caching and make sure your secrets are always fresh.

Comment: When using Vault, you wouldn't mount a Configmap